# "execution completed. Click here to switch design mode, or select stop debugging from the debug menu

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, execution

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition on Windows 2014 Server.
I have opened the existing SSIS project from visual studio 2015 I have problem with my SSIS package. When I'm trying to debug it I get information "Package execution completed. Click here to switch design mode, or select stop debugging from the debug menu". But on my flow there in no task
with green mark indicated that task is completed correctly, no task with red mark indicated that task is completed with error and no task with yellow mark indicated that task is in progress. Do You have any ideas what could be the reason? Or is there any log where error could be explain in more details?
Thanks in advance!

Note if i try to create a new package and execute it is working fine.

Comment: What does the package do?   Maybe there is nothing present for it to execute on.

Comment: No, my package has ExecuteSQLTask & DataFlowTasks.